# How to clip Bézier curves using Casteljau's algorithm?

Tags: parametric, bezier-curve

I am attempting to approximate intersections of Bézier curves using iterative clipping.

This common method is described [here](http://nishitalab.org/user/nis/cdrom/cad/CAGD90Curve.pdf) and [here](http://www.tsplines.com/technology/edu/CurveIntersection.pdf).

It basically works like this:

1. Find bounding lines outside one curve.
2. Clip the other curve to these lines.
3. Alternate and repeat.

[image]

There are some extra cases to handle (multiple intersections), but that's the idea.

I get stuck on step (2). In a one sentence explanation, both sources say to use de Casteljau's algorithm to clip the curve $P$ to between $t_1$ and $t_2$.

> Bézier clipping is completed by subdividing $P$ twice using the de Casteljau algorithm, such that
>   portions of $P$ over parameter values $t < 0.25$ and $t > 0.75$ are removed.

I understand how to use de Casteljau's to split a curve on a single $t$ value, but not multiple.

How is this intended to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets call the original curve $C1$, and suppose we want to clip it to the parameter interval $[0.25, 0.75]$. We do this by applying de Casteljau splitting twice.

First, split $C1$ at $t=0.75$. Keep the "left" portion (the one corresponding to $[0,0.75]$) and throw away the right portion. Call the resulting curve $C2$.

Now we want to split $C2$. The split has to happen at the point $P$ that corresponds to $t=0.25$ on the original curve $C1$. The only subtlety is that the point $P$ corresponds to $t=\tfrac13$ on the curve $C2$, because $0.25 = \tfrac13*0.75$. So, split $C2$ at $t=\tfrac13$, and keep the right-hand portion, $C3$. The curve $C3$ is the one you want.

Comment: Interesting. How is $1/3 * 0.75$ justified? I had thought of that, but didn't see why it should work.

Comment: We want the point that is at $t=0.25$ on $C1$. What is the value of $0.25$ relative to the interval $[0,0.75]$? Answer: it is one third of the way along that interval. So the relevant parameter value on curve $C2$ is $\tfrac13$.